# Auto Fill and Fit CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a CSS grid that auto sizes and auto-fills in my items. Currently, I'm trying to make the grid items autofill, which is not working. The items are spaced way too far apart. Secondly, I want to make it fit to device size. I.e. if it is a smartphone: one column, if it is a tablet: two columns, if it is a computer: four columns. Just know the code below is part of a larger website but I'm attaching it all anyway in case it interferes with anything else.

```css
:root{
  --grid-size: 200px;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #1F363D;
  overflow: hidden;

}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #BBBBBB;
  color: #1F363D;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #808782;
  color: white;

}

body{
  margin: 0px;
}

a{
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
}

p{
  font-family: monospace;
}

h1 {
  font-family: monospace;
}

h2 {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000088;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-item img{
  width: var(--grid-size);
  height: var(--grid-size);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-color:#1F363D;
}

.grid-holder {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: var(--grid-size) var(--grid-size) var(--grid-size) var(--grid-size);
  grid-templete-rows: var(--grid-size) var(--grid-size) var(--grid-size) var(--grid-size);
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  pading: 5px;

}



.grid-item{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;

  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid-item a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1F363D
  font-size: ;
}

.grid-item a:visited {
  color: #1F363D;
}

.grid-item a:hover {
  color: #000088;
}

.grid-item a:active {
  color: #000088;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
}

.column {
  flex: 50%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  text-align: center;

}

.column img {
  width: auto;
  height: 75vh;
  display: block;
}

.column button {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000088;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #000088;
  height: 40px;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  margin-top: 10px;

}

      .column button:hover{
        color: white;
        background-color: #000088;
        transition-duration: 500ms;
      }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Portfolio</h1>
  <h2>Projects</h2>
</div>
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
  <a class="active" href="/projects.html">Projects</a>
  <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="/about.html">About</a>
</div>




<div class="grid-holder">
  <a class="main-link" href="/projects/mastermind.html">
    <div class="grid-item" id="mastermind-holder">
      <img src="/images/mastermind-icon.png">
      <a class="link" href="/projects/mastermind.html"><strong>Mastermind</strong></a>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="/projects/simon.html">
    <div class="grid-item" id="simon-holder">
      <img src="/images/simon-icon.png">
      <a class="link" href="/projects/simon.html"><strong>Simon</strong></a>
    </div>
  </a>
</div
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the grid container, you can try using this rule to make them fluid:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, var(--grid-size));
```

This will fill the container with columns of size "--grid-size", adding empty columns if there is enough space for them.

If instead you do not want new empty columns to be created, you can use `auto-fit` instead of `auto-fill` as the first parameter for the "repeat" function above.

[In this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat) you can learn more about dynamic grid columns using the "repeat" function.

Here it is an updated snippet of your code, I did some editing on the grid container class (removed auto margin and used justify-content to center the columns in the screen).
Also, I removed the link that it's outside of the items, because there was a link inside too. It's not possible in html to put two links one inside of the other, since this causes some wrong html interpretation.

Here it is:

```css
:root{
  --grid-size: 200px;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #1F363D;
  overflow: hidden;

}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #BBBBBB;
  color: #1F363D;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #808782;
  color: white;

}

body{
  margin: 0px;
}

a{
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
}

p{
  font-family: monospace;
}

h1 {
  font-family: monospace;
}

h2 {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000088;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-item img{
  width: var(--grid-size);
  height: var(--grid-size);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-color:#1F363D;
}

.grid-holder {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, var(--grid-size));
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  pading: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
}



.grid-item{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;

  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid-item a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1F363D;
}

.grid-item a:visited {
  color: #1F363D;
}

.grid-item a:hover {
  color: #000088;
}

.grid-item a:active {
  color: #000088;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
}

.column {
  flex: 50%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  text-align: center;

}

.column img {
  width: auto;
  height: 75vh;
  display: block;
}

.column button {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000088;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #000088;
  height: 40px;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  margin-top: 10px;

}

.column button:hover{
  color: white;
  background-color: #000088;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Portfolio</h1>
  <h2>Projects</h2>
</div>
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
  <a class="active" href="/projects.html">Projects</a>
  <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="/about.html">About</a>
</div>




<div class="grid-holder">
    <div class="grid-item" id="mastermind-holder">
      <img src="/images/mastermind-icon.png" />
      <a class="link" href="/projects/mastermind.html"><strong>Mastermind</strong></a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item" id="simon-holder">
      <img src="/images/simon-icon.png" />
      <a class="link" href="/projects/simon.html"><strong>Simon</strong></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works pretty well, but for some screen sizes (such as full screen in web browser and landscape mobile) it looks a little weird.

Comment: @tb_03 , from the keywords of your question , take a loot at this example https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example37/ it shows difference between auto-fit and auto-fill . The example can be edited here https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/dpYzZq , so you can play with it and test and see behaviors to match your requirements. Grid is very powerfull and has many options, and limits too at tone point ;) . Do not hesitate to dig into tutorials and live example for your own .

Comment: I forked the codepen and have messed around with it. Here is what I have. https://codepen.io/tb_03/pen/QWaBeja . My problem is that when I copied and pasted that code for the grid-holder into my project, I still had the centering problem.

Comment: @tb_03 Related to centering: please consider that the code above will center **the columns** rather then the objects themselves. If you use the devtools to inspect the grid, you will see that on desktop it has multiple columns that are empty. That is caused by auto-fill. If you just want 200px elements that are always centered and wraps when the screen is too thin, I think you should consider using flexbox rather then grid.

Comment: You can also try using `auto-fit` instead of `auto-fill`. Applied to the example above, [this is the result](https://jsfiddle.net/vwzLj1at/1/). I've also updated my answer to specify what auto-fill and auto-fit do (very briefly).

Comment: I realized my error was I never fixed the double linking issue. I completely overlooked that. It works now.